# Arrayformulas and how to format them using COUNTIF and IF statements

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

long time reader, first time poster! I had recently took on the task of creating a new roster for something and I am currently at an impasse using ARRAYFORMULA with IF statements and COUNTIF. The code blocks are rather large to post, however, I have included a copy of the roster [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hd80garbP1uEcfCsVK6rSV_d6C20lotW3VeOZQSZpWE/edit?usp=sharing).

EDIT: This is for the Knight+ Roster tab, which is to calculate eligibility for promotions, IF Column B blacklist is not current = 0, IF columns F and G contain a keyword, column J date exceeds 6 days, and the count for column P is greater than or equal to 1 then the statement is True and they are eligible for promotion considering their Knight rank which does have different requirements.

If you look at R31, it is the exact same formula without Array, and its statement is True, vs L31 where it is false.

Also, as far as the count if portion, if you look at the W column, it shows counting 4, when in fact it should be counting 1.

Any helping reducing my migraine of trying to solve this riddle would be appreciate, if in fact I am just making this harder on myself than I need to, and should just be using individual columns/rows for formulas. My want is to have to reduce the amount of editing I have to do over the long run in case changes in requirements are made down the road, as well as making it much simpler for people who have no experience in upkeeping code to a minimum by having to worry about 1 formula, rather than 1000 rows of formulas.

Comment: Sean, I just took a quick look at your sheet and formula in question (which, for the sake of other contributors who may read, is in the sheet "Knights + Roster"—a detail not specified in the post). Your formula in R31... (how to say this kindly)... makes no sense. I don't think a single element of the formula is used correctly. So it's not clear what you were trying to do. You also have the sheet set to "Comment only," which means no one can open your hidden columns to see what's in Col J or others you reference in the formula(s).

Comment: For starters, I recommend that you change the permission on the sheet link to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" for the reasons stated above. Second, you'll need to explain in detail what you are trying to do and what you expect the result to be. For any contributor who chooses to invest their time into this, I think they'll need to built the formula from scratch; and that will require a full understanding of the end goal.

Comment: I have updated the link to an edit link, originally I was going too, but, the hidden columns are redundant as they hold no use and I was only hiding them to lessen the scrolling I had to do. The one set that is referenced in the code, I did hide by mistakes, but all the times set, were true (longer than 6 days). I have updated the requirements as per how it is set now in the formula.